# com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [997] Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to mount some network device using WNetAddConnection2W an constantly get the
*com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [997] Overlapped I/O operation is in progress*.
Before each run I do check that there is no previous mapping left. Also the net use command is working perfectly.
How can I solve this issue?

Here is my code

```
public static final String remotename = "\\\\10.10.19.33\\C$";


public int WNetAddConnection2A(NETRESOURCEA lpNetResource, String lpPassword, String lpUserName, int dwFlags) throws LastErrorException;
public int WNetAddConnection2W(NETRESOURCEW lpNetResource, WString lpPassword, WString lpUserName, int dwFlags) throws LastErrorException;

private NETRESOURCEW setNetresourcew() {
        NETRESOURCEW lpNetResource;
        lpNetResource = new NETRESOURCEW();
        lpNetResource.dwScope = 0;
        lpNetResource.dwType = NETRESOURCE.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
        lpNetResource.dwDisplayType = NETRESOURCE.RESOURCEDISPLAYTYPE_SHARE;
        lpNetResource.dwUsage = NETRESOURCE.RESOURCEUSAGE_CONNECTABLE;
        lpNetResource.lpLocalName = null;
        lpNetResource.lpRemoteName = new WString(remotename);
        lpNetResource.lpComment = null;
        lpNetResource.lpProvider = null;
        return lpNetResource;
    }

  @Test
  public void testW() {
      NETRESOURCEW lpNetResource = setNetresourcew();

      WString lpPassword = new WString(password);
      WString lpUserName = new WString(username);

      int dwFlags = Mpr.CONNECT_TEMPORARY;
    
      try {
        int errorCode = Mpr.INSTANCE.WNetAddConnection2W(lpNetResource, lpPassword, lpUserName, dwFlags);
    
        if (errorCode == 0) {
            errorCode = Mpr.INSTANCE.WNetCancelConnection2W(lpNetResource.lpRemoteName, 0, 1);
        }
      } catch (LastErrorException ex){
          System.out.println("Mounting Windows Share: " + ex + " " + ex.getErrorCode() + " " + ex.getCause());
          Mpr.INSTANCE.WNetCancelConnection2W(lpNetResource.lpRemoteName, 0, 1);
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Last error exception should not be thrown from the  WNetAddConnection2 definition since it troughs ANY exception, even if it was through not by this call.

Comment: Yes, it is. (some how can not mark it as correct answer)